# Is there any way to use git from behind a proxy on Ubuntu to clone github repositories without having to rebuild it myself with openssl?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, openssl, gnutls

Is there a working git for Ubuntu 18 which can clone git repositories form github from behind a proxy without running into the infamous GnuTLS recv error?

Key question is this:

Can this be done without having to rebuild one's own git package with openssl? -- This is something I'm unlikely to do due to various system requirements. Please suggest alternatives. Furthermore, recommending such a package rebuild when git actually works from behind a proxy with smaller repositories on github seems to be an overkill.

Here is the story of the problem.

When using git (2.21.0) on Ubuntu (18.04.1) to clone opencv repository from github, the following error is encountered.

```
$ git clone http://github.com/opencv/opencv.git opencv
Cloning into 'opencv'...
warning: redirecting to https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git/
remote: Enumerating objects: 2, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 251542 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 251540
Receiving objects: 100% (251542/251542), 457.18 MiB | 1.82 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): 
The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

As you can note above, the problem is encountered after the whole repository has been downloaded.

In the meantime, "$ git config --list" shows the following as set (as some answers have recommended).

```
https.sslverify=false
https.postbuffer=1048576000
http.sslverify=false
http.postbuffer=1048576000
```

PLEASE NOTE -- Small repositories can be cloned without any problem, directly, from github. For example, the following can be cloned without any issues: https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo

===>>>> The problem is encountered when cloning relatively large repositories such as opencv, for example, as noted above.